# how to clear an image on button click

Tags: wpf

How do I clear an Image with the click of a button. I already use bt_ClearOnclick to remove data from text boxes.

```
private void btClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtId.Text = String.Empty;
        txtvalue.Text = String.Empty;
        image?
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void btClear_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtId.Text = String.Empty;
    txtvalue.Text = String.Empty;
    image.Source = null;
}
```